# EXCEL GET CELL/ export the data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table that I want to export the data to a table that contains a column of names, dates and attendance so that it takes the values ​​from the table
like this picture
[image]

Comment: You want INDEX/MATCH.  I'll write up a google sheet so you can see it.  It would be handy in the future if your data wasn't in a picture.

Answer (score 0):

You want INDEX and MATCH.  See the formula at this Google Sheet, but it will work the same in Excel  This is the top of the two examples:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bvp6-Jb82A-AEOxvnMLzUNxWUSCKt1merc2nfSt3viE/edit?usp=sharing

```
=INDEX(F10:M13, match(O13, F10:F13, 0), match(P13, F10:M10, 0))
```

INDEX takes a range, and two numbers, one for the row and one for the column, and returns the value (or reference) at that intersection.  You can pass false or null for either one of the numbers and return the entire row or column of the range, or if you are working with a single dimensional array, like a row or a column, you can just pass one number to it.

MATCH takes a value and a range (and an optional lookup type) and returns the index of that value in the range.

So using INDEX with two MATCHes, you can find the row and column of the data you are looking for.

DOCS:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a

---

It is possible to do this with VLOOKUP, but I find INDEX/MATCH to be more intuitive and more flexible.  Here is a VLOOKUP implementation.  It is the bottom of the two examples on the demo sheet:

```
=vlookup(O16, F10:M13, match(P16, F10:M10, 0))
```

As you can see, you still pass it the data range and use match to get the column, but VLOOKUP will find the row with the lookup value for you, *as long as it is in the first column*.  INDEX/MATCH lacks this limitation, and I find the arguments more logical: INDEX(range, row, column) vs VLOOKUP(lookup value, range, column).

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Rf1DdWg-5x04yl1OYn3IWuzZKwPF7CWFrfABGbhXqfA/edit#gid=0

Comment: Sorry, I can't access that.  You'll probably want to change the share settings.